# Rails 3 - How to refactor this piece of code?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring

I would like to refactor this piece of code which is not DRY at all :)

```
def my_method
 if session[:my_params].try(:include?, :answer)
   session[:my_params][:answer]
 elsif session[:my_params].try(:include?, :question)
   session[:my_params][:question]
 end
end
```

Is there a way to implicitly return either `:answer` or `:question` depending on which one is present (if present) in `session[:my params]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hash will return `nil` if a key has no value associated in it.  Because `nil` and `false` are both handled the same in conditionals, we can shorten this method very aggressively.  The `if session[:my_params]` ensures that the `session[:my_params]` is not nil.

```
def my_method
  session[:my_params][:answer] || session[:my_params][:question] if session[:my_params]
end
```

Comment: Perfect, works great, I should have thought of that before :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_method
  session[:my_params][:answer] || session[:my_params][:question]
end
```

will return `nil` if neither are present.

This of course assumes that `[:answer]` and `[:question]` values are not intentionally false, e.g. `false`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_method
  h = session.fetch(:my_params, {})
  h[:answer] || h[:question]
end
```